# Postgresql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

Ubuntu 14
I install postgresql server on remote server(digitalocean).

Run command psql and display errors:

```
postgres@ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01:/home/deploy$ psql
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "be_BY.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "be_BY.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "be_BY.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "be_BY.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "be_BY.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "be_BY.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "be_BY.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "be_BY.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "be_BY.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I want reload postgresql server, run command `service postgresql start --force`

```
* No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
```

I think problem with locale setting. But how solve this error?

Comment: locale is just a warning - it won't prevent `psql` from connecting. what `pg_lsclusters` shows?..

Comment: on `locale` warnings read http://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue

Answer (score 0):

locale warning won't prevent `psql` from connecting. Read https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue on this.

> No PostgreSQL clusters exist

means that you probably did not create a cluster. Run smth like `pg_createcluster -p 2345 9.5 test` to create a test cluster, or better read `man pg_createcluster` as Ubuntu suggested

Answer (score 0):

Walk this way

- Find the cluster

  ```
  pg_lsclusters
  ```
- Drop your cluster (Use the information from above)

  ```
  pg_dropcluster --stop 9.3 main
  ```
- Create the cluster anew

  ```
  pg_createcluster --locale en_US.UTF-8 --start 9.3 main
  ```
- Login to postgres

  ```
  sudo -u postgres psql
  ```
- And check locales

  ```
  show LC_COLLATE;
  show LC_CTYPE;
  ```
  -